# Insert HTML By jQuery Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked at the multiple methods of inserting HTML with javascript, both with jQuery .prepend and .innerHTML and I keep getting the same output no matter what I do:

```
'); }
```

I am trying to insert HTML if the screen resolution if of a certain width. These are the two scripts I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >

if (screen.width >= 500)
{
$('#stemanimation_hype_container').prepend('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="STEM%20Animation_Resources/stemanimation_hype_generated_script.js?58608></script>');

}
</script>

<div id="stemanimation_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:900px;height:300px;">
</div>
```

The other:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >

if (screen.width >= 500)
{
document.getElementById("stemanimation_hype_container").innerHTML='<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="STEM%20Animation_Resources/stemanimation_hype_generated_script.js?58608'></script>";

}

</script>
<div id="stemanimation_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:900px;height:300px;">
</div>
```

Any idea what may be going on? I am testing this on a page with only jquery and no other scripts to ensure no conflicts. Thank you for any help you can give me!

Comment: why are you adding charset="utf-8". I don't think you need that.

Comment: I'm using Hype to build animations, thats what it told me to do,but even without, it makes no difference

Answer (score 6):

you have an error in the string defining the html to insert

```
'<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="STEM%20Animation_Resources/stemanimation_hype_generated_script.js?58608'></script>";
```

should be:

```
'<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="STEM%20Animation_Resources/stemanimation_hype_generated_script.js?58608"></script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first block of code is missing a `"` after `?58608`

Your second block of code has a `'` where there should be a `"` after `?58608`, and vice-versa for the end of the string.

Try

```
$('#stemanimation_hype_container').prepend('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="STEM%20Animation_Resources/stemanimation_hype_generated_script.js?58608"></script>');
```

Comment: dbaseman's example give me no brackets but no animation, jackwanders' give me brackets again.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is good, but this error:

```
..._script.js?58608"></script>');
                // ^ Forgot a "
```

Alternatively I may recommend using `document.createElement` and append it to the container though:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '..._script.js?58608';
document.getElementById('stemanimation_hype_container').appendChild(script);
```

Or, the jQuery way:

```
$('<script>',{
  'type' : 'text/javascript',
  'src' : '..._script.js?58608'
}).appendTo('#stemanimation_hype_container');
```

*(Note I use `...` in the code for brevity, not accuracy)*

Comment: @BenjaminMorrison: Not sure what the issue is. Given this is hand-written script, the premise of attachment is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/BVJTK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$('#stemanimation_hype_container').html('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="STEM%20Animation_Resources/stemanimation_hype_generated_script.js?58608"></script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is the actual code you're trying, you've got an unmatched double quote in the jq example, and a double closing a single in the other version.

Comment: What is your expected result? Since you're injecting a script, what do you hope to have happen?

Comment: I used a program called hype to create javascript/html/css3 animations. It works BEAUTIFULLY, but I just can't seem to get this to work conditionally with screen resolution. The site is responsive and I need to have different animations called/inserted depending on screen resolution.

Comment: If I upload it to my server would you guys mind taking a look yourself?

Comment: brmceramics.com/tiesrev/testing/STEM%20Animation.html

Comment: the one that works with the recommended code is here:

http://www.brmceramics.com/tiesrev/testing/STEM%20Animationworking.html

Answer (score 0):

in both examples, i see inconsistent usage of quotes in your src attributes. you started with a double quote but ended with a single quote. try ending it with a double quote.

Comment: I fixed the quotes, no dice. If anyone wants to take a look it's at this address: http://www.brmceramics.com/tiesrev/testing/STEM%20Animation.html

Comment: Oh and FYI, I know jack squat about javascript.

Comment: I'm getting the following HTML:'); }
Looks like an issue with the js file.

Comment: I didn't know that could be an issue. I thought that by calling the file by HTML, it wouldn't clash. I asked the Tumult forums but so far no bites

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the script block at the end of your HTML.  Right now, you are looking for $('#stemanimation_hype_container') before that div has been inserted into the DOM, and so it doesn't exist when the JS is run.  That's why nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

My issue in getting this to work properly was actually a nasty conflict with Tumult Hype's script for CSS3 animation. The code examples, with the exception of my typo regarding the double quotes, is actually correct for most applications.